# QCheckbox signal emits for all chechboxes even if only one is toggled in pyQT?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qcheckbox

```
def updateDataDictionary(self, opt, idx, param, check):
    """Populates the ScrollArea for Storage Enabling on Hub basis
    :param opt: Option tells what to modify: technology(0) or storage(1)
    :type opt: Integer

    :param idx: The id for the hub which needs to be modified
    :type idx: String

    :param param: The Technology/Storage which needs to be modified
    :type param: String

    :returns: None
    :rtype: None
    """
    if(check.isChecked()):
        if(opt == 1):
            self.data_dictionary[idx]["Technologies"][param]["Enabled"] = "1"
        elif(opt == 2):
            self.data_dictionary[idx]["Storages"][param]["Enabled"] = "1"
    else:
        if(opt == 1):
            self.data_dictionary[idx]["Technologies"][param]["Enabled"] = "0"
        elif(opt == 2):
            self.data_dictionary[idx]["Storages"][param]["Enabled"] = "0"


for i in range(len(self.data_dictionary.keys())):
        temp_check = QCheckBox()
        temp_check.setText(str(self.data_dictionary.keys()[i]))
        if(self.data_dictionary[self.data_dictionary.keys(
        )[i]]["Technologies"][self.dock_tab3_1.techCombo.currentText(
        )]["Enabled"] == "1"):
            # Make the Checkbox checked
            temp_check.setChecked(True)
        else:
            # Make the Checkbox un-checked
            temp_check.setChecked(False)
        temp_check.stateChanged.connect(partial(
            self.updateDataDictionary, 1, self.data_dictionary.keys()[i],
            self.dock_tab3_1.techCombo.currentText(), temp_check))
        temp_layout.addWidget(temp_check)
```

Here, I have a ScrollArea which has a list of checkboxes. The issue is that when on the GUI, a checkbox is toggled the updateDataDictionary method is being called for all the checkboxes in the scrollArea instead of only the one which was toggled.

So, ideally only one of the entry must go from 1 to 0, when corresponding check-box is toggled. But all of the entries in my dictionary get modified to 0.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: When you ask a question you must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You could show the updateDataDictionary method

Comment: just made the edit @eyllanesc sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I have tested the code and I do not observe the problems you get, you could provide the complete code and everything you need to run it.

Comment: Can you post your code. I can't send you everything because it's a huge software and not very straight-forward to run this code.

Comment: see this: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/c1b0ffbe5c01ea576ab7e5b46a7dadb7

Comment: this works fine on my system as well. But I don't know what the issue in the above code.

Comment: You could try to create a widget similar to mine that shows the behavior of your code to be able to help you.